# I want to save the data which is display on the command prompt while compiling a process

Tags: 12.04, installation, wireless, redirect

I want to save or copy the data which is displayed at the command prompt while compiling a process.

For example, if I want to install a tool like LIGHTTPD, I want to save whatever I do and see in the terminal to a file..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question completely. Are you trying to save the output from the install process or the commands performed during the install (or both)?

Comment: You can see what you have been doing with the command `history | less`, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output to a file using the `>` symbol:

```
install-command > file.txt
```

If you want to review the inputs (commands) that you made during the install, type `history` to dump the contents of your history file.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you execute the command **make** to compile. To save the output seen on the terminal to a file, use the command **script -c "make"** . The output will be saved in a file called **typescript**.

Comment: Hai Jay,   I take a LIGHTTP server then compile it giving the commands./configuration,make and etc.. when we type ./configuration , it displays something process by each and every command . I want copy that all information from the starting

Comment: script -c "./configuration; make ; nextcommand "

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to the system using a terminal emulator, it may have session logging. You can then enable that. When you open a new terminal to connect, (or select a bookmark,) you'll have a complete history of everything you do, every time. You may toss most of the connection logs, but this way you never have to remember to start logging.